# How to replace variant array text in QT QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i want to replace string text in qml.
for example,
QML variant array exist. and i use to Text.

```
property variant    szString: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

and

```
i do data in szString.
szString[1] = "abcdefg"
szString[2] = "a###b"
...
```

and

```
Text: {
    text: szString[index]
    ...
}
```

i want to replace string at this text.
For example,

```
i want szString[2].replace("#"," "). (i want result -- szString[2] = "a   b" )
but, the QML language can't apply.(szString.replace("#"," ") can apply, but this result isn't... i don't want result)
```

Please help me....

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Maybe what you want is: `szString[2].replace(new RegExp("[#]+", "g"), " ")`?

Comment: `i want szString[2].replace("#"," "). (i want result -- szString[2] = "a   b" )` what kind of programming language is that? Please make sure that the code blocks contain **runnable code** and no other texts (appart from properly marked comments) are in the code block.

Answer (score -1):

```
while (szString[2].search("#") > -1) szString[2] = szString[2].replace("#"," ")
```